# How to iterate on all entites in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my ModelContext I have function for Register Query Filters which I run in `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` method.

```
private void RegisterQueryFilters(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Apple>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.ProductId == ProductId);
            builder.Entity<Orange>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.ProductId == ProductId);
            builder.Entity<Kiwi>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.ProductId == ProductId);
            builder.Entity<Banana>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.ProductId == ProductId);
        }
```

Always when I adding new Entity then I have to put it here. But I'm afraid that some day someone will forget to add this here. Is it any way to force user to add it here somehow? Or maybe iterate on all Entity and do the same function to all of them. Something like this:

```
private void RegisterQueryFilters(ModelBuilder builder)
{
     foreach (var entity in AllEntity)
     {
        builder.Entity<entity>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.ProductId == ProductId);    
     }
}
```

Comment: If all the entities are in a namespace you could use reflection to get all the types and call the `builder`

Comment: Can you give me some advice how to do this? Maybe some good article about reflection as it's totally foreign to me. :)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.types(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Types), it should help.

Answer (score -1):

there is a nuget package: EntityFramework.DynamicFilters if you are on EF 6

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters/

I think even in EF 7/core it is supported out of the box (no need for that nuget)

first: let all your entitities implement an interface or inherits from an abstract class (in the next line it is called EntityBase)

second: add this to the OnModelCreating in your DBContext

```
modelBuilder.Filter("IsDeleted", (EntityBase d) => d.Deleted, false);
```

Grtz

Comment: This assumes that all types inherit a common class/interface, which is exactly what the OP doesn't want

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understand your requirements completely, but I guess what you would profit from is a list of all types derived from a class

```
List<Type> knownTypes = new List<Type>();
foreach(Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        knownTypes.Add(t);
}
```

Comment: This assumes that all types inherit a common class/interface, which is exactly what the OP doesn't want

Comment: If they have nothing in common (which could be encoded in a common interface) then I ask myself how he should be able to iterate over them in a loop?

Comment: As was mentioned in a comment: *Reflection*.